# Font adds small left margin that can't be overridden with CSS

Tags: html, css

As you can see in the following snippet, the first letter of the word "Rails" has some baked-in space that can't be removed with CSS, therefore it doesn't align with the other element. I've rest as many Browser-styles as possible, still the margin remains.

Can someone explain why does this happen/where is this margin coming from and then ways to circumvent it?

```css
.debug-border {
  border-left: 1px solid blue;
}
.main-title {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <h3 class="main-title">Rails</h3>
      <!--We are an international tech company etc etc..-->
      <p class="debug-border">We are an international tech company.
        <br>We build products.</p>
      <div class="addmargin-top-xl">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">what we do</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We have answers to questions as [1, 2, 3, 4] votes... `:D`

Comment: haha! :) true .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be considered a **hack**. But if this works, you are free to go ahead. Use negative `text-indent`. Mind it, it is not scalable.

```css
.debug-border {
  border-left: 1px solid blue;
}
.main-title {
  font-size: 100px;
  text-indent: -5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <h3 class="main-title">Rails</h3>
      <!--We are an international tech company etc etc..-->
      <p class="debug-border">We are an international tech company.
        <br>We build products.</p>
      <div class="addmargin-top-xl">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">what we do</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: Thank you Praveen but I am not looking for a hack; I'd like the answer as to _why_ this happens. (and of course a non hack solution would be very welcome), I'll rephrase my question.

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos AFAIK, this is a hack. Some people consider this as the solution. This happens because of the kerning.

Answer (score 2):

The width of a single letter in a font usually accounts for a little margin before and after it, to make the letters in words keep the right distance; else the text would appear too cramped (kerning is used to adjust such distance for pairs of letters but it doesn't matter here).

The space you see is part of the letter "R" and can't be adjusted using CSS. You can use a negative margin, but it is quite an hack and it won't work with all font sizes: you'll need to determine the correct value for the font size you will be using.

Comment: Actually, if you size the negative indent in em instead of px, it will handle any font size - given the values in the answer above, set `margin-left` or `text-indent` to -0.05em instead of 5px. The answer below, which uses -6px, would suggest a `margin-left` or `text-indent` of -0.06em.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can use a negative `margin-left` value on `.main-title`:

```css
.debug-border {
  border-left: 1px solid blue;
}
.main-title {
  font-size: 100px;
  margin-left: -6px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <h3 class="main-title">Rails</h3>
      <!--We are an international tech company etc etc..-->
      <p class="debug-border">We are an international tech company.
        <br>We build products.</p>
      <div class="addmargin-top-xl">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">what we do</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the same as mine... `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar sorry - when I started, there was no answer yet... (but it's not completely the same: you used text-indent, I used margin-left)

Comment: Na... That's fine. This is similar. Not exactly dupe. `:D`